# react form, delete previous state if length < 1

Tags: reactjs, forms, object, state

I want to make a form with multiple fields but I only want to populate the fields that are actually being used, for example in the following code, if the length of the field is over 1, it will appear, but if I delete it and it becomes 0, then I don't want to keep the data in state, but the way I have it, the field still shows  `sku: 45FGH, title: ""` , I need it to get rid of the data that has nothing at all, as if it was never populated. so in the previous case, since I typed something in title and deleted it afterwards, I only want to keep `sku: 45FGH`  in state and get rid of `title: ""`

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

function TheForm() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({})
  const handleChange = (e, key) => {
    if(e.target.value.length >= 1) return setData(prevState => {
      return {...prevState, [key]: e.target.value}
    })
  }
  console.log(data);
  return (
    <div>
      <input placeholder="sku" onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, 'sku')}/>
      <input placeholder="title" onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, 'title')}/>
      <input placeholder="location" onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, 'location')}/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default TheForm
```

the main issue is that I am using graphql, and if I provide a field, it must contain something, and sometimes I do not use all fields, and if I mistakenly type something in one of the fields, it will break the POST request.

the thing is, is not about being rendered, its about the data being kept in state, lets say I have 3 fields, sku, title, and location. if I only want sku and location Ill type it and only those 2 fields get created or added into state, title is never added, but if i type something in title and then delete it, then the 3 of them are now active with the title being empty. which is not what I want, I need the title to be completely gone from state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution, I made a separate object which pushes only the fields being used.
a big THANK YOU to the people who tried!

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

function TheForm() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({})
  const handleChange = (e, key) => {
    return setData(prevState => {return {...prevState, [key]: e.target.value}})
  }
  let _obj = {}
  for(let [key, value] of Object.entries(data)){
    if(value.length > 1) _obj[key] = value;
  }
  console.log(_obj);
  return (
    <div>
      <input placeholder="sku" onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, 'sku')}/>
      <input placeholder="title" onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, 'title')}/>
      <input placeholder="location" onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, 'location')}/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default TheForm
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid messy code, you should strive to keep logic out of JSX when possible. In some cases like this it's useful to use a [Conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) that returns null instead of your component when not true. For example:

```js
function TheForm() {
  ...
  return (
    <form>
      { data.sku.length() > 0 ? <input value={data.sku} ... /> : null }
      ...
    </form>
  )
}
```

Comment: this does not work in my case, I need the input to be displayed at all times. I don't want the empty fields to be sent over or to be kept in state. but thank you tho

Comment: I apologize, I used the wrong wording when doing my question, I edited it, to make it a little more understandable